# Interaction in spin models

Tags: interactions, spin-models

In the Heisenberg Spin model, the spin components of spins in the same direction at different lattice sites couple together. Is there a physical scenario where, say, the $x$ Spin component of a spin half particle couples with the $y$ Spin component of another spin half particle?

Answer (score 1):

I'll add my comment as an answer.

I think what you are looking for is the antisymmetric exchange interaction (also called DM interaction). It takes the form $$H_{DM} = D_{ij} \cdot \mathbf{S}_i \times \mathbf{S}_j $$

Here $\mathbf{S}_i$ is the spin operator on site $i$ and $D_{ij}$ is a vector that describes the strength of the antisymmetric exchange interaction between the spins at site $i$ and $j$.

Note that if you write the spin operator as $$\mathbf{S}_i = S_{i,x} \hat{x} + S_{i,y} \hat{y} + S_{i,z} \hat{z}$$
and carry out the cross product you will get the couplings of the form $S_{i,x} S_{j,y}$ etc. That you are interested in.